# Does $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 \text{ and } \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=0 \implies \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

**The Problem**

Say
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 \text{ and } \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=0 \, .
$$
Does this imply that $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0 \, ?$$
I understand that $f(x)$ must become very small relative to $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$, but I'm worried that my intuitions might be failing me here.

**What I have tried so far**

For some neighbourhood of $a$, it seems evident that $|f(x)|\leq|g(x)|$. (Otherwise, the limit wouldn't equal $0$.) Consider the case where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are nonnegative. Then, we are left with $0 \leq f(x) \leq g(x)$. Since
$$
\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=\lim_{x \to a}0=0 \, ,
$$
the squeeze theorem seems applicable here. However, I'm not sure how to generalise this result to when $|f(x)|\leq|g(x)|$, nor am I certain how to show that $|f(x)|\leq|g(x)|$ in the first place.

Comment: Hint : put $h(x)=f(x)/g(x)$. You have $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$.

Comment: I would use L'hopital here if you can. The answer to your question is obviously yes. I think if you want to go down the road you're going, a little more analysis is required. Don't take any step for granted.

Comment: hint:think of mean value theorem

Comment: @Kelenner I think I've got it now, thanks. Since $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, we have $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}g(x)h(x) = \lim_{x \to a}g(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to a}h(x) = 0 \cdot \lim_{x \to a}h(x) \, .$$ Since $\lim_{x \to a}h(x)$ exists, we conclude that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=0$. You may post your comment as an answer if you wish.

Comment: I have written an answer on paper with epsilons and deltas, but I don't have time until later to write the answer on here :'(

Comment: A stronger result is if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)/g(x)=b\in\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange $~f(x)~$as $~f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot g(x)~$, then $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot g(x) =\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot \lim_{x \to a}  g(x) = 0 \cdot 0=0~.$$

Comment: Thanks, it was nice to see an alternative method. It looks like I was overcomplicating things...

Comment: Welcome @Joe.
Don't worry, it happens for all.

Answer (score 0):

Overcomplicating things is not always bad. Maybe it will help you improve your $\epsilon-\delta$ proof skills. I'll prove the contrapositive by assuming $\neg \left(\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0\right)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=0$, and show that $\neg \left(\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\right)$. Let us examine what each of these statements means.

First, define $E_{z,\alpha} = (z-\alpha,z)\cup(z,z+\alpha).$

$\neg \left(\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0\right)$ is equivalent to the statement:

$\exists r>0$ such that $\forall \gamma>0,\ \exists \ x_\gamma\in  E_{a,\gamma}$  such that $|f(x_\gamma)-0| = |f(x_\gamma)| > r.$

Next, $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=0$ is equivalent to the statement:

$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $|f\left(x\right)-0| = |f\left(x\right)| <\varepsilon,\ \forall x \in E_{a,\delta}.$

We want to show that $\exists r'>0$ such that $\forall \beta > 0, \exists x_\beta \in E_{a,\beta}$ such that $\frac{|f(x_\beta)|}{|g(x_\beta)|} > r'.$

To this end, let $\beta > 0$ and then let

$
\beta'=
\begin{cases}
 \beta&\text{if}\, 0<\beta\leq 1\\
 \frac{1}{\beta}&\text{if}\, \beta > 1.\\
\end{cases}
$

Then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $ |g(x)| < \beta' \leq \beta \quad \forall \ x \in E_{a,\delta}$.

Also, $\exists x' \in E_{a,\delta}$ such that $|f(x')| > r.$

So now it makes sense to let $r' = r.$

Therefore, $\frac{|f(x')|}{|g(x')|} > \frac{r}{\beta'} \geq r$ for this $x' \in E_{a,\delta}.$

In other words, $r' = r$, and we have shown that $\exists r$ such that $\forall \beta > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\exists x' \in E_{a,\delta}$ with $\frac{|f(x')|}{|g(x')|} > r,$

i.e. $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}$ does not exist.